# nodejs nested module arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Basically, I'm trying to clean up my code and I dont want to have to do mc.module1(mc.ticket,function(data){}); I just want to have the module container hold the ticket and automatically pass the ticket into the separate module functions when they are called.

So, how would I do something like this.

```
***main.js
     var mc = recuire('modulecontainer.js');
     mc.module1(funtion(data){//bla bla do something with data});

***modulecontainer.js
     var module1 = require('module1.js');
     var module2 = require('module2.js');
     var ticket="someChangingAuthenticationCode";
     module.exports={
         module1:module1(ticket),
         module2:module2(ticket)
     }
     function updateTicket(){
          //code that updates the authentication ticket at the required interval
     }


***module1.js
     module.exports={
         a:function(ticket,callback){
            //bla bla use authetication ticket to request some data....
            callback(data)
         }
     }

***module2.js
     ///bla bla very similar to module1 just requesting and proccessing different data
```

Comment: cant you just use "curry" functions for that? https://medium.com/@adambene/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400

Comment: module.exports = (ticket) => {
  return (callback) => {
    // ticket exists here
    callback(data)
  }
}